# Freeradius no authentication method found

Tags: asterisk, freeradius

I have Asterisk server with Freeradius server on the same machine and trying to authenticate with Radius if a user can make a call or not but I am getting an error while calling that is:

```
ERROR: No authenticate method (Auth-Type) found for the request: Rejecting the user
Failed to authenticate the user.
```

Is there something that I am missing in one of Radius files that I have to add?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that no module in the authorize section of your virtual server has taken responsibility for processing the request.

You should remove the contents of the authorize section, and list the following modules:

```
authorize {
    pap
    chap
    mschap
    digest
    eap
}
```

You should then run the server in debug mode `radiusd -X` to see which module is taking responsibility for the request (you'll see one returns `ok` or `updated` where the others return `noop`). We'll call this the `auth module`

Once you've figured out which module will take responsibility for the request you'll need to provide a suitably hashed password.

Here are the password hashes that will work with the different modules.

- pap - any
- chap - `Cleartext-Password`, `CHAP-Password`
- mschap - `Cleartext-Password`, `NT-Password`
- digest - `Cleartext-Password`, `Digest-HA1`
- eap - Depends on inner method (respond to this answer and I can give further guidance).

For testing you can put the password in a flat file local to the server. The module which deals with these flat files is the `files` module.

To add entries to the users file, first truncate `/etc/raddb/users` (alter for your installation).

Then add the following entry to the top:

```
<username>  <password attr> := <password>
```

With values in `<>` replaced with the real values.

Remove the unused modules in authorize, and add the `files` module at the top.

```
authorize {
    files
    <auth module>
}
```

Then remove all the modules from authenticate and add the `<auth module>`

```
authenticate {
    <auth module>
}
```

That should give you up and running. If no modules take responsibility for the request, please post the list of attributes in the request from the top of the debug output, and i'll help you identify it.

Answer (score 0):

You need configure your radius to add missing headers

You can enabled full debug on radius server, it will show you all packets radius server get.

Freeradius allow add any header into packet on any stage, see doc.

Comment: I did look at RADIUS packets and RADIUS is receiving the request from Asterisk server to Authenticate the client but nothing is going out of RADIUS no reply at all. But I didn't add anything to RADIUS about the clients that I have I should maybe that is the problem

Comment: So you configured radius wrong. You should put int config what to answer on such packet(sql or other rule) and radius will do for you. Nore, freeradius is just set of libs for radius protocol. Without configuration it do nothing, but VERY flexible.

Comment: Okay I get it now I am new to RADIUS and I am trying to learn it more do you have any useful links that I can look at that would be great 
Thanks